# How do I query the results of a 'group by' query, all within the same query

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine I have the following data in a table Example:

```
Price, Amount, Type
100, 3, A
80, 6, A
190, 16, A
50, 250, A
30, 2, B
55, 7, B
11, 3, B
```

In a single query I want to get all the elements of type A, ordered in ASCENDING order of price and all the elements of type B, ordering in DESCENDING order of price

I want to do it in a single query since the table updates very frequently and it would be disasterous if the data changed in between the two queries.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could just use a transaction to ensure consistent read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Price, Amount, Type
FROM yourtable
WHERE Type='A'
ORDER BY Price ASC

UNION ALL

SELECT Price, Amount, Type
FROM yourtable
WHERE Type='B'
ORDER BY Price DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am wondering how I access this data. Say I have while($myrow = mysql_fetch_object($result)){ // do stuff } how do I get the first 15 of type A and the first 15 of type B? After that then I am done with this...

Comment: put a `LIMIT 15` on each subquery. retrieving the results of this would be just like any other normal non-union query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Price, Amount, Type
FROM tableX
WHERE Type IN ('A','B')
ORDER BY Type, 
         CASE WHEN Type='A' THEN Price ELSE (- Price) END ;
```